# How to apply different conditional format to different rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, conditional-formatting

I have the following dataframe:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBi6V.png

I used the following code to highlight the max values of every cell:

```
def highlight_max(s):
    try:
        is_max = s == s.max()
        return ['background-color: red' if v else '' for v in is_max]
    except TypeError:
        pass
    except KeyError:
        pass
    
s = df.style.apply(highlight_max, axis=1)
s
```

But I just want to apply this formatting to a certain row, for example the row 'Book Value Per Share (mrq)'.
I can't find any code that helps me with this!!!

Anyone knows?

Comment: HEELLLLLLLLPPPPPPPP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `subset` argument, passing a tuple `(row_indexer, column_indexer)` like so...

```
s = df.style.apply(highlight_max, axis=1, subset=(0, df.columns))
```

The row indices are zero-based, so `0` represents the first row, that you want to format.

More details here in the official docs here: [Finer control: slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-control:-slicing)

Comment: Done! Do you know if I can apply more than one condition for example some rows I want the maximum but to others I just want the minimum?

Comment: If you add a `highlight_min` function, then you can replace the call to `apply()` with 2 calls to `applymap()` & again passing the `subset` argument to define the rows you want each style to be applied to. If you get stuck, then you could ask a new question, let me know & I'll have a look

Comment: Sorry to disapoint you sir! But I wasn't capable, I am noob yet and those callable function eat my brain! If you want to give it a try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619931/how-to-add-more-than-two-formatting-conditions-to-different-row-in-a-dataframe