# How to add more than two formatting conditions to different row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, conditional-formatting

I asked this question [How to apply different conditional format to different rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618135/how-to-apply-different-conditional-format-to-different-rows) that was kindly answered by @davmos

Now I have a new problem, that is add more than two condtions in different datarows!

So I have the following dataframe: [image]

Where I am highlighting the max values in the coloured rows, but i also want to add other conditions in other rows. For example the minimum value in the 'FORWARD P/E' row

So my code is the following :

```
def highlight_min(s):
try:
    is_min = s == s.min()
    return ['background-color: green' if v else '' for v in is_min]
except TypeError:
    pass
except KeyError:
    pass

def highlight_max(s):
    try:
        is_max = s == s.max()
        return ['background-color: green' if v else '' for v in is_max]
    except TypeError:
        pass
    except KeyError:
        pass



df.style.apply(highlight_max, axis=1, subset=(['Book Value Per Share (mrq)', 'Diluted EPS (ttm)','EBITDA', 'Gross Profit (ttm)'], df.columns))
```

My question is how I can use those other conditional formulas in other rows in the same dataset!

Thank you very much :)

Comment: You could apply those conditional formulas separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you concatenate the APPLY function for each function you want, you can do multiple processes. I didn't have the data, so I got AAPL's income statement and adapted it. I changed the minimum value to red.[refer to pandas style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

```
(df.style.apply(highlight_max, axis=1, subset=(['Research Development', 'Operating Income','Cost Of Revenue'], df.columns))
.apply(highlight_min, axis=1, subset=(['Research Development', 'Operating Income','Cost Of Revenue'], df.columns)))
```

[image]